# Mostrar los datos con formato correcto en Java

Tags: java, array, tablas

**Buenos días, estoy haciendo un programa en Java que en un array bidimensional almacena (de forma aleatoria) distancias entre las provincias de Andalucía. Lo tengo prácticamente todo hecho salvo un pequeño error que no consigo solucionar a la hora de mostrar los datos, se me muestran así:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

(Almería en horizontal no debería estar justo encima de Almería en vertical, porque queda una columna que parece que no tiene provincia)

¿Cómo lo soluciono? Dejo el enunciado del ejercicio y el código que tengo, muchas gracias de antemano.

Enunciado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]**

Código:

```
    import java.util.Scanner; //importar scanner

    public class problema1 {   

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        //activar scanner
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        //arrays
        String[] provincias = {"Almería", "Cádiz", "Córdoba", "Granada", "Huelva", "Jaén", "Málaga", "Sevilla"}; //array unidimensional para almacenar las provincias
        int[][] distancia = new int[provincias.length][provincias.length]; //array de 2 dimensiones para las distancias

        //generar distancias aleatorias
        for (int i = 0; i < provincias.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < provincias.length; j++) {
                if (i != j) { //esta condición es para evitar que se genere una distancia entre una ciudad y sí misma
                    distancia[i][j] = (int) (Math.random() * 600) + 1; //en el enunciado del ejercicio la mayor distancia que aparece es "600", así que he decidido dejar esa como máxima
                    distancia[j][i] = distancia[i][j]; //asignar la misma distancia en la posición inversa
                }
            }
        }

        //mostrar tabla
        System.out.println("    ");
        for (int i = 0; i < provincias.length; i++) {
            System.out.printf("%10s", provincias[i]);
        }
        System.out.println();
        for (int i = 0; i < provincias.length; i++) {
            System.out.printf("%-10s", provincias[i]);
            for (int j = 0; j < provincias.length; j++) {
                System.out.printf("%10d", distancia[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        } //corregir que no hay suficiente espacio en horizontal

        //pedir las ciudades
        System.out.println("Por favor, escribe el nombre de la ciudad origen: ");
        String ciudadOrigen = sc.nextLine(); //nombre de la ciudad origen
        System.out.println("Por favor, escribe el nombre de la ciudad destino: ");
        String ciudadDestino = sc.nextLine(); //nombre de la ciudad destino

        //buscar las posiciones de las ciudades en el array

            //declaración de variables
            int posicionOrigen = -1;
            int posicionDestino = -1; //inicializadas a "-1" para evitar problemas en el recorrido del array

            //recorrer el array
            for (int i = 0; i < provincias.length; i++) {
                if (provincias[i].equals(ciudadOrigen)) {
                    posicionOrigen = i;
                } else if (provincias[i].equals(ciudadDestino)) {
                    posicionDestino = i;
                }
            }

        //mostrar la distancia entre las ciudades
        if (posicionOrigen != -1 && posicionDestino != -1) {
            System.out.printf("La distancia entre " + ciudadOrigen +" y " + ciudadDestino + " es de " + distancia[posicionOrigen][posicionDestino] +  " km.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Alguna de las ciudades introducidas no es válida.");
        }
    

        //cerrar scanner
        sc.close();
}


}
```

Comment: facil en el horizonatal mete un string vacio de espacio al principio

Comment: ¿Dónde sería eso? Es que he probado en varios lugares pero no sale

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cidgo arreglado, te dicho que era cuestion de meter un campo mas :P, la tabal esta arreglada pero da un pete no se exactamente xq

```
     import java.util.Scanner; //importar scanner

    public class problema1 {   

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        //activar scanner
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        //arrays
        String[] provincias = {"Almería", "Cádiz", "Córdoba", "Granada", "Huelva", "Jaén", "Málaga", "Sevilla"}; //array unidimensional para almacenar las provincias
        String[] provincias2 = {"","Almería", "Cádiz", "Córdoba", "Granada", "Huelva", "Jaén", "Málaga", "Sevilla"};
        int[][] distancia = new int[provincias.length][provincias2.length]; //array de 2 dimensiones para las distancias

        //generar distancias aleatorias
        for (int i = 0; i < provincias.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < provincias.length; j++) {
                if (i != j) { //esta condición es para evitar que se genere una distancia entre una ciudad y sí misma
                    distancia[i][j] = (int) (Math.random() * 600) + 1; //en el enunciado del ejercicio la mayor distancia que aparece es "600", así que he decidido dejar esa como máxima
                    distancia[j][i] = distancia[i][j]; //asignar la misma distancia en la posición inversa
                }
            }
        }

        //mostrar tabla
        System.out.println("    ");
        for (int i = 0; i < provincias2.length; i++) {
            System.out.printf("%10s", provincias2[i]);
        }
        System.out.println();
        for (int i = 0; i < provincias.length; i++) {
            System.out.printf("%-10s", provincias[i]);
            for (int j = 0; j < provincias.length; j++) {
                System.out.printf("%10d", distancia[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        } //corregir que no hay suficiente espacio en horizontal

        //pedir las ciudades
        System.out.println("Por favor, escribe el nombre de la ciudad origen: ");
        String ciudadOrigen = sc.nextLine(); //nombre de la ciudad origen
        System.out.println("Por favor, escribe el nombre de la ciudad destino: ");
        String ciudadDestino = sc.nextLine(); //nombre de la ciudad destino

        //buscar las posiciones de las ciudades en el array

            //declaración de variables
            int posicionOrigen = -1;
            int posicionDestino = -1; //inicializadas a "-1" para evitar problemas en el recorrido del array

            //recorrer el array
            for (int i = 0; i < provincias.length; i++) {
                if (provincias[i].equals(ciudadOrigen)) {
                    posicionOrigen = i;
                } else if (provincias[i].equals(ciudadDestino)) {
                    posicionDestino = i;
                }
            }

        //mostrar la distancia entre las ciudades
        if (posicionOrigen != -1 && posicionDestino != -1) {
            System.out.printf("La distancia entre " + ciudadOrigen +" y " + ciudadDestino + " es de " + distancia[posicionOrigen][posicionDestino] +  " km.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Alguna de las ciudades introducidas no es válida.");
        }
    

        //cerrar scanner
        sc.close();
}


}
```

Comment: No entendí a lo que te referías. Muchas gracias por la ayuda